# Fixed last column of the table

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me about css? I want my last column of the table is fixed. The first and second columns that are auto layout but third to be fixed on the right side of the div element.

```
<div>   
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>

</table>
<div>
```

Comment: do you need fixed width? OR do you need the text inside the last column to be aligned right side?

Comment: fixed means position or width ?

Comment: position, last column to be in right side of div element

Comment: @user3661837 something like this [ https://jsfiddle.net/25oo1rt9/ ] ??

Comment: Yes, but the right side of the div, not the whole page

Comment: @user3661837 understand place an answer [ https://jsfiddle.net/25oo1rt9/1/ ]

Answer (score 0):

This way

```css
table{width:100%;}
table td{border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<div>   
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td width="100">text</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>

</table>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment, in case you need fix width for last column you can try following

```
<div>   
 <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td width="250px">text</td> <!-- or width="30%" -->
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>

</table>
<div>
```

in case you just need the content of the last column to be aligned right try following.

```
<div>   
 <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">text</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td style="text-align:right;">text</td>
        </tr>

</table>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this. you can set all the last column right side of the div. [LiveFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25oo1rt9/1/) . If any question ask me in comment.

```css
table{
  width:100%;
}
td:last-of-type {
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div>   
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>
 <tr >
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
        <td>text</td>
    </tr>

</table>
<div>
```

Comment: Thank yoy! Now i have this https://jsfiddle.net/17s8gz3L/. I need flexible lenght of first two columns when I'm entering text, but fixed lenght of third column and that table doesn't leave div (doesn't move the div). Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @user3661837 remove the white space and overflow from td and just add word-break: break-word; and check the table will be inside the red border. 
Thanks

Comment: Thank you. But i don't need all text to be shown, i need just a part that can fit in the first and second column, limited with third colmn. Field can ends with "..."